Do conservative force fields excert zero torque over rigid bodies? (The force acts on every part of the body)
I read Andrew H. answer in Torque produced by conservative forces vs Torque produced by non-conservative forces  but couldn't understant why the last integral is zero. Answers justifying (or disproving) this are welcomed.

That integral looks like a misapplication of Gauss's divergence theorem, i.e., it is incorrect.

Counter-examples:

A long narrow object in a nonuniform gravitational field will experience a torque on it due to tidal forces, until it is aligned with the local gradient of the field

A compass needle being turned by Earth's magnetic field to point North


Additional note:
An irrotational vector field means that an infinitesimal sticklike object with length $d \ell$
will not pick up any rotation from the field. I.e. the curl of the field is zero. So that part is correct. But extended objects of finite length can indeed pick up rotation or torque from an irrotational field

The needle is subject to the nonconservative force of the pivot, and can you prove that an object in free space aligns with the gradient of the field?

The needle could be floating on a body of water, which only acts to cancel gravity, and the same thing would happen.

The force that acts on the needle only acts on its tip. So doesn't apply. Furthermore, I don't understand how tidal forces produce torque on a rigid body.

That's not accurate

still, how do you know that the needle would rotate in free space (or the ocean)?

In the magnetic case, the object rotates until its own magnetic field lines are aligned with the field lines of the Earth, because this configuration has the lowest energy. In the gravitational case, the rotation occurs because different parts of the object are pulled on at different strengths.

I read your linked answer.  An irrotational vector field means that an infinitesimal sticklike object with length $dl$ will not pick up any rotation from the field. I.e. the curl of the field is zero. So that part is correct. But extended objects of finite length can indeed pick up rotation or torque from an irrotational field

Using Andrew H.'s own arguments, if you choose a surface that does encompass the object, then the integral is no longer null.
The fallacy of Andrew's arguments lies in the fact that when you calculate the total torque exerted on a body by a force, you must integrate over the volume of the body.
Why? Because each particle of the body is subjected to $\overrightarrow{F}$. Outside the body, there is no particle and no torque. So Andrew's choice of S outside the body is wrong.
$$\vec \tau = \int _{V_{body}} \vec r \times - \vec \nabla U ( \vec r ) dV = \oint _{ S_{body}} - U ( \vec r ) \vec r \times \vec n d\sigma$$

do you have an example of the integral being nonzero?

The integral
$$\oint _ S U ( \vec r ) \vec r \times \hat n d\sigma $$
is zero for a sphere, because the it can be split, taking $\vec r = \vec R + \vec r'$, where $\vec R$ is the position of the centre of the sphere, and $\vec r'$ is the vector from this centre to the sphere surface:
$$\oint _ S U( \vec R ) \vec R \times \hat n d\sigma = U( \vec R ) \vec R \times \oint _ S \hat n d\sigma = 0$$
Because the integral of the unit normal around all the sphere is zero. And:
$$U( \vec r' ) \vec r' \times \hat n = U( \vec r' ) \vec r' \times (-\hat r') = U( \vec r' ) [\vec r' \times (-\hat r')] = 0$$
But if we have a semi sphere for example, the integrand above in $r'$ is zero only at the points in the curved surface part. In the plane of section $\vec n$ is constant, but the cross product is not zero. Calling this plane $S'$:
$$\oint _ {S'} U( \vec r' ) \vec r' \times \vec n d\sigma = [\oint _ {S'} U( \vec r' ) \vec r' d\sigma] \times \vec n$$
Clearly, the integral is only zero in the particular case where $U( \vec r' ) = U( |\vec r'| )$, that is when it is radially symmetric. Otherwise, the contribution of each $\vec r_ 0'$ is not compensated by a $-\vec r_ 0'$.
So, the integral is not zero in the general case.

What do you mean by U(|r'|)?

It is when the potential is a function only from the distance to the centre of the sphere. $|r'| = \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}$.
